# JOptionPane gives an error

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, event-dispatching, substance

I want to handle some exceptions using `JOptionPane`s. This is the main method:

```
public class MainRun {

public static void main(String args[]){    
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SubstanceRavenGraphiteGlassLookAndFeel());
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                 
            new MainGui().setVisible(true);                
            new Initialized().start();
            new PriorityMessageQueue().start();
        }
    });
```

`MainGui` is the main window (`JFrame`) of the application.
I handled exception inside the `PriorityMessageQueue` thread.

```
public class PriorityMessageQueue extends Thread {

@Override
public void run() {

    while (true) {
        try {
            instantMessages = instant.getMobitelMessagesToBeSent();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                        null,
                        ex.getMessage(),
                        "Database Error",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }

        ...
```

after I run this, I'm getting an error

```
   org.jvnet.substance.api.UiThreadingViolationException: Component creation must be done on Event Dispatch Thread
at org.jvnet.substance.utils.SubstanceCoreUtilities.testComponentCreationThreadingViolation(SubstanceCoreUtilities.java:2312)
at org.jvnet.substance.SubstanceOptionPaneUI.createUI(SubstanceOptionPaneUI.java:83)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:37)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:244)
at javax.swing.UIDefaults.getUI(UIDefaults.java:752)
at javax.swing.UIManager.getUI(UIManager.java:989)
at javax.swing.JOptionPane.updateUI(JOptionPane.java:1859)
at javax.swing.JOptionPane.<init>(JOptionPane.java:1822)
at javax.swing.JOptionPane.<init>(JOptionPane.java:1785)
at javax.swing.JOptionPane.<init>(JOptionPane.java:1753)
at javax.swing.JOptionPane.<init>(JOptionPane.java:1731)
at javax.swing.JOptionPane.<init>(JOptionPane.java:1711)
at GUI.MainGui.showOptionPane(MainGui.java:1039)
at SMS.PriorityMessageQueue.run(PriorityMessageQueue.java:86)
    UIDefaults.getUI() failed: createUI() failed for
      javax.swing.JOptionPane
   [,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=0,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,p
   referredSize=,icon=,initialValue=,message=DatabaseConnection class
   connect,messageType=ERROR_MESSAGE,optionType=DEFAULT_OPTION,wantsInput=false]
   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   java.lang.Error
at javax.swing.UIDefaults.getUIError(UIDefaults.java:712)
at javax.swing.MultiUIDefaults.getUIError(MultiUIDefaults.java:133)
at javax.swing.UIDefaults.getUI(UIDefaults.java:758)
at javax.swing.UIManager.getUI(UIManager.java:989)
at javax.swing.JOptionPane.updateUI(JOptionPane.java:1859)
at javax.swing.JOptionPane.<init>(JOptionPane.java:1822)
at javax.swing.JOptionPane.<init>(JOptionPane.java:1785)
at javax.swing.JOptionPane.<init>(JOptionPane.java:1753)
at javax.swing.JOptionPane.<init>(JOptionPane.java:1731)
at javax.swing.JOptionPane.<init>(JOptionPane.java:1711)
at GUI.MainGui.showOptionPane(MainGui.java:1039)
at SMS.PriorityMessageQueue.run(PriorityMessageQueue.java:86)
```

And the `JOptionPane` will not display properly!

[image]

Instead of passing `null` to `JOptionPane`, how can I get the parentComponent (`MainGui` `JFrame`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `JOptionPane` is a mini Swing GUI, and like all Swing GUIs, it must be created on the Swing event thread, not on a background thread. This can be done by creating your `JOptionPane` in a `Runnable` and then queuing the `Runnable` on the event thread:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(....);
  }
});
```

For example,

```
} catch (Exception ex) {
   final String exMessage = ex.getMessage();

   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
         null,
         exMessage,
         "Database Error",
         JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
       );
     }
   });
  }
}
```

As for your question,

> Instead of passing `null` to `JOptionPane`, how can I get the parentComponent (`MainGui` `JFrame`)?

You'll need a reference to the main GUI. How you get this will depend on how your program is organized.

Answer (score 3):

- `Substance` is EDT very sensitive, all updates must be done on EDT
- otherwise you can see only `toolbar` (came from `Native OS`) from `Swing JComponen`ts
- or exceptions from `RepaintManager` (I think that from `Trident` package)
- `JOptionPane` must be wrapped into `invokeLater()`, then your `JOptionPane` coudl be visible,
- I think your `exception` talking about another issue, something hidden in your code, maybe there isn't something with used `Substance L&F`, this is secondary issue